# Prove that $\{(x,x)\mid x\in \mathbb R\}$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R),m)$ a measurable space. How can I prove that $E:=\{(x,x)\mid x\in \mathbb R\}$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^2$ ? My definition of measurable in $\mathbb R^2$ is $$ E\in \sigma \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\},$$
where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ denote the Borel set.

In fact it's much more complicated than what I thought, because I tried to find $A,B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $E=A\times B$, but I can't. I was thinking of something as $\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb R}\{x\}\times \{x\}$, but it's for course not measurable. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

- **Method 1 :** Denote $p_1(x,y)=x$ and $p_2(x,y)=y$. Of course, there are measurable, and thus so is $p_1-p_2$. Set $f=p_1-p_2$. Since $$E=f^{-1}(\{0\}),$$
  it's measurable.
- **Method 2 :** If you really want to write $E$ as a union/intersection of element of the form $A\times B$ where $A,B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, set $$A_{k,m}=\left[\frac{m}{2^k},\frac{m+1}{2^k}\right[\times \left[\frac{m}{2^k},\frac{m+1}{2^k}\right[,$$ and you'll get that $$E=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb Z}A_{k,m}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $E$ is a closed set. Closed sets are Borel measurable.